# JLabel during mousePressed don't delete a previous text

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jlabel

I created few JLabels for display values (from MySQL) which must switch via mousePressed but after each click all values lay over others.

What need do for clearing previous text during display new values? Maybe there are have a better element for my aim than JLabel?

```
    jt.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) { }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            String director = null;
            String year = null;
            String bestrole = null;
            String genre = null;
            String mors = null;
            String production = null;
            String rate = null;
            String time = null;
            String date = null;
            if (me.getClickCount() == 1) {
                int typ = jt.getSelectedRow();
                if (typ>-1) EditButton.setEnabled(true);
                if (typ>-1) DeleteButton.setEnabled(true);
                {
                    try {
                        Connection conn2;
                        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        Statement stmt2 = (Statement) conn2.createStatement();
                        String title = String.valueOf(jt.getValueAt(jt.getSelectedRow(), 0));
                        String query2 = "select * from movie where title='"+title+"'";
                        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);
                        rs2.next();
                        director = rs2.getString("Director");
                        year = rs2.getString("Year");
                        bestrole = rs2.getString("BestRole");
                        genre = rs2.getString("Genre");
                        mors = rs2.getString("Mors");
                        production = rs2.getString("Production");
                        rate = rs2.getString("Rate");
                        time = rs2.getString("Time");
                        date = rs2.getString("Date");
                    }
                    catch (Exception er) {System.err.println(er);}
                }
            }
            JLabel labDirector = new JLabel("Director: "+director);
            panel1.add(labDirector, constT1);
            JLabel labYear = new JLabel("Year: "+year);
            panel1.add(labYear, constT2);
            JLabel labBestrole = new JLabel("Best role: "+bestrole);
            panel1.add(labBestrole, constT3);
            JLabel labGenre = new JLabel("Genre: "+genre);
            panel1.add(labGenre, constT4);
            JLabel labMors = new JLabel("Type: "+mors);
            panel1.add(labMors, constT5);
            JLabel labProduction = new JLabel("Production: "+production);
            panel1.add(labProduction, constT6);
            JLabel labRate = new JLabel("Rate: "+rate);
            panel1.add(labRate, constT7);
            JLabel labTime = new JLabel("Time: "+time);
            panel1.add(labTime, constT8);
            JLabel labDate = new JLabel("Date: "+date);
            panel1.add(labDate, constT9);
            panel1.revalidate();
            System.out.println(director);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the labels by calling remove() function on the them.
Suppose you want to modify 'labDirector' label, you can do:

```
panel1.remove(labDirector);
```

to remove the previous label and then add the modified label as:

```
panel1.add(labDirector, constT1);
```

as you did in your code.

You can do this for all the labels to modify them.

**UPDATE**

You can try this also:

Declare the JLabel(s) globally:

```
JLabel labDirector;    // Global declaration
```

and access them in the function as:

```
labDirector = new JLabel("Director: "+director);
```

The global declaration will ensure that every time you use `labDirector` label, you are accessing the same instance of JLabel every time.

Now, after removing old labels and adding new labels to the panel, you have to repaint the panel to update it with the new values. You can do this:

```
panel.remove(label1); // Remove the old label
labDirector = new JLabel("Director: "+director); // assign new value to new label
panel.add(label1); // add new label
panel.revaidate(); // revalidate panel
panel.repaint(); // repaint the window to update it
```

Hope this helps:)